# JSON RECORRERLO

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Tengo este JSON

```
{
    "id":2,
    "group_id":1,
    "default_billing":"2",
    "default_shipping":"2",
    "created_at":"2018-10-03 16:12:55",
    "updated_at":"2018-10-03 16:13:00",
    "created_in":"Default Store View",
    "email":"henryarcila@gmail.com",
    "firstname":"Henry",
    "lastname":"Arcila",
    "store_id":1,
    "website_id":1,
        "addresses":[{
            "id":2,
            "customer_id":2,
                "region":{
                    "region_code":"NY",
                    "region":"New York",
                    "region_id":43
                    },
                "region_id":43,
                "country_id":"US",
                    "street":[
                                "123 Oak Ave"
                            ],
                "telephone":"512-555-1111",
                "postcode":"10755",
                "city":"Purchase",
                "firstname":"Henry",
                "lastname":"Arcila",
                "default_shipping":true,
                "default_billing":true
        }],
        "disable_auto_group_change":0
}
```

Ese JSON lo obtuve de esta linea de codigo:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
```

Ya que esto lo estoy extrayendo de una consulta de REST, yo quiero guardar ese JSON en una variable y de allí ir extrayendo cada uno de estos campos que estan dentro del **ADDRESSES**:

> firstname, lastname, region_code, region, region_id,country_id,
>   street, telephone, postcode y city.

Al momento de obtenerlas yo las quiero guardar en variables diferentes y tenerlas almacenadas porque luego en otras respuestas del REST que necesito tengo que cargarle otro JSONObject esas variables, un ejemplo es esto:

```
JSONObject JshippingAddress = new JSONObject();
                JshippingAddress.put("email", "henryarcila@gmail.com");
                JshippingAddress.put("region", "New York");
                JshippingAddress.put("region_id", 43);
                JshippingAddress.put("region_code", "NY");
                JshippingAddress.put("country_id", "US");
                JshippingAddress.put("street", JCalle);
                JshippingAddress.put("postcode", "10577");
                JshippingAddress.put("city", "Purchase");
                JshippingAddress.put("telephone", "512-555-111");
                JshippingAddress.put("firstname", "Henry");
                JshippingAddress.put("lastname", "Arcila");
```

En estos momentos se las paso HARD CODE, cabe destacar que están en diferentes clases por ello guardo variables GLOBALES en un controller.

Comment: Debes mapear el objeto en una clase o clases ya que al parecer es un objeto compuesto, una vez teniendo tus clases puedes acceder a sus propiedades

Comment: Hola Andrea agrega como has tratado de obtener los valores, es para Android o JavaScript?

Comment: viendo la pregunta otra vez encunetro que hay una confusion, es java o javascript? porque tiene las dos etiquetas la pregunta

Comment: es java, en android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero veamos que `addresses`es un array dentro del `JSONObject` entonces para acceder a el:

```
JSONArray jsonAdress = json.getJSONArray("addresses");
```

Pero ese array trae dentro 13 JSONObject así que hay que recorrerlo para acceder a cada uno.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#JSONObject()) para manejar el json como un objeto y así poder tomar el valor de alguno de sus campos:

```
JSONObject miJson = new JSONObject(<tuJSON>); //JSONObject (String json)
String field = miJson.get("fieldName").toString()); //Object get (String name)
```